# Regex for Number Range 200 - 800 in Increments of 10

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to validate GMAT scores, which go from 200 - 800 in increments of 10. So far, I have been able to come up with validating all numbers from 200 - 800:

`^([2-7][0-9]{2}|800)$`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you just want to end with a literal 0

```
^([2-7][0-9]0|800)$
```

Comment: This could be simplified(?) to `^([2-7]\d|80)0$`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight I like the \d, but moving the 0 to the very end is just a little too confusing.

Comment: @Humdinger Well, with regex, anything that "simplifies" the regex often makes it more confusing to read, hence my "simplified(?)"

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it?

```
^([2-7][0-9]0|800)$
```

Increments by 10 means it has to end by zero.

Comment: Good Job! You happened to get the exact same answer as the guy before you!